# How to get localStorage setItem after 1 hour?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

On click of a close icon, the user not able to see the notification screen. How should I show it again the same screen to the user after 1 hour...please guide

```
const [hideLearningMaterialClosed, setHideLearningMaterialClosed] = useState(false)
useEffect(() => {
const { user = {} } = JSON.parse(localStorage.auth || '{}')
localStorage.getItem(`learning_material_closed_${user.id}`, dayjs().add(1, 'hour').toString(),) && 
setHideLearningMaterialClosed(true)
})

{!hideLearningMaterialClosed && (
    <Row
      style={{
        background: '#F05757',
        fontSize: '11px',
        color: 'white',
        lineHeight: '15px',
        height: '45px',
        width: '100%',
        padding: '8px',
        maxWidth: '766px',
        wordSpacing: '1px',
        position: 'fixed',
        bottom: '61px',
      }}
    >
      <Col span={23}>
        Add learning material to your schedules to avoid class cancellation.
        <span style={{ fontWeight: '600' }}>Click here</span>
      </Col>
      <Col span={1}>
        <CloseOutlined
          style={{ marginTop: '10px' }}
          onClick={() => {
            const { user } = JSON.parse(localStorage.auth)
            localStorage.setItem(`learning_material_closed_${user.id}`, dayjs().add(20, 's').toISOString())
            setHideLearningMaterialClosed(true)
          }}
        />
      </Col>
    </Row>
  )}
```

Comment: Probably need to create a timestamp of when to show the notification, and when the site is loaded check if the timestamp is equal to or later than the set date, if not create a `setTimeout` function to show the notification using the remaining minutes/seconds etc

Comment: Alternatively, you could just use a plain old-fashioned cookie with an expiration date, instead of localStorage (which doesn't have expiration dates.)

Answer (score 0):

After storing a value into `localstorage` you have to start `setTimeOut` for 60 minutes which will call a function that remove the value from `localstorage` once 60 minutes completed.

Comment: No need to remove the value. See dw_'s comment on the question.